# Input tipo=date, que no permita días pasados

Tags: html5

estoy en búsqueda de una validación para HTML, en especifico para un input tipo date, el cual no permita ingresar o seleccionar días pasados, o sea, que solo permita seleccionar el día actual o futuros! De antemano gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y también a realizar el [tour]. En cuanto a tu pregunta, ¿qué has intentado por tu cuenta? Si puedes agregar a tu pregunta el código de lo que hayas intentado, sería preferible. Saludos

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Debes añadir algo de lo que haz intentado, además de esclarecer mejor las tecnologías que deseas usar para esto y las que no quieres usar, para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Si haces esto, recibirás mejor calidad en las respuestas. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se puede hacer solo con  HTML, necesitas javascript para cambiar el atributo `min` del input. Teniendo en cuenta que la fecha tiene que estar en formato `YYYY-MM-DD`, una posible solución es:

```js
document.getElementById('input-fecha').min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

```html
<input type="date" id="input-fecha"/>
```

Comment: Esto no es correcto. Sí se puede realizar con html: sería un `input` de tipo `date` con el atributo `min` con el valor de hoy (o ayer).

Comment: Lo que he hecho es justo cambiar el atributo "min" con Javascript. El valor de "hoy" es diferente cada día

Comment: Ya veo. El `max` me había descolocado

Comment: Sí, lo había respondido al revés, ya está editado

Comment: Lo puse en practica y me funcionó muy bien! Muchas Gracias!!!